# How do I actually apply my Android icon pack to a user's icons?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-icons

I recently designed an icon pack for Android and I've got the icons finished. I am now looking to start designing the app to actually apply them. I've looked around and most of the material I've found seems to be out of date or for Eclipse (I'm using Android Studio). I don't want anything fancy, just a button to auto apply my icons to a user's phone. Can anyone help me out or point me in the direction of more information on this? Thanks.

EDIT: For instance here are some of the icons I made myself and manually applied them to my phone [http://i.imgur.com/EBc1o05.png](https://i.imgur.com/EBc1o05.png)

I'm looking to do that, except in an app and at the push of a button rather than manually setting ~200 app icons.

Comment: "I don't want anything fancy, just a button to auto apply my icons to a user's phone" I don't exactly get what you aiming for, where should these icon be applied to?

Comment: @Alex applied to whatever apps the user has on their phone that I have a made an icon for. Just standard icon pack functionality in things like Nova Launcher

Comment: Can you give an example of what your app will do with the icons? Maybe a screenshot of something similar or a mockup? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelVescovo I edited the original post. Something like this (these are icons I made and set manually, looking to do it automatically in app) http://i.imgur.com/EBc1o05.png